# Trigger click event of button whose nearest textbox is focused

Tags: angular, typescript

I have dynamic cards in the view. There is a text box on each card and a button next to it. I want to trigger click event of the button of that card whose text box is focused by "Enter Key". The cards shown in the picture. Also I am struggling in clearing the contents in the text box of the card selected.

[image]

I tried clearing contents of textbox using ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('bidamount') txtbidamount: ElementRef;

this.txtbidamount.nativeElement.value = '';
```

But with this approach only the textbox of the first card gets cleared.

Comment: Add your **cards** component with typescript code??

Comment: Added card components with *ngFor

Comment: Is the enter key thing is doable ?

Comment: I have posted an answer please check below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code generates multiple components, you should probably use '**ViewChildren**' and '**QueryList**' rather than the singular '**ViewChild**'.

So write in card component using this:

```
@ViewChildren('bidamount') inputBidAmount: QueryList<ElementRef>;
getClickAmount(index, item) {
    console.log(index,this.inputBidAmount.toArray()[index])
    console.log(this.inputBidAmount.toArray()[index])
}
```

In Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i =index">
   <input type="text" id="{{'txt'+ item.id}}" #bidamount/>
   <button (click)="getClickAmount(i, item)">Bid</button>
</div>
```

**UPDATED Stackblitz**
 [Trigger click event of button whose nearest textbox is focused](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhb7yo?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Hope this help you!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this. But its not working in my case. Actually when I am clicking button and logging this.txtbidamount.toArray() in console. I am getting all the 3 textbox whereas in fiddle that you provided only one textbox element is displayed and that's why you are able to clear the textbox

Comment: can you create a stackblitz where you got three textbox

Comment: @AkshayDusane here you have pass index to that function to retrieve specific html dom??

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a good workaround. But now I want to trigger click event of the button of that card whose text box is focused by "Enter Key".

Answer (score 1):

> also I am struggling in clearing the contents in the text box of the card selected.

Since you haven't provided any code here is some that will work:

- Given the input has some identifier e.g. `id` attribute `me`, the following code clears the `before` value from the input

```js
document.getElementById('me').value = ''; // clear value
```

```html
<input value="before" id="me"/>
```